Do restaurants have patios or terraces in the US and in Canada? What's the difference?
Restaurants often have outdoor areas which are often referred to as either patio or terrace on the Internet. A wikipedia article about patio says restaurants have patios as outdoor areas but I have seen on the Internet that restaurants in countries whose official language isn't English are often said to have terraces.
As far as I know on house-related contexts, the terms are interchangeable but I was even told by a native speaker that referring to the outdoor eating area of a restaurant as a terrace was odd.

If you add the link to Wikipedia page in your question, I'll upvote it.

It might also be a courtyard. Some restaurants just call it dining al fresco, to avoid that dilemma.

Yes.
Restaurants often have outdoor areas which are often referred to as either patio or terrace, though other terms might be used (garden, courtyard, outside seating) . The choice is mainly a matter of marketing, and there is little significant difference in meaning.
If you look at the range of senses, you'll see that a "Patio" is a paved area, whereas a terrace is a flat, sometimes raised area.  A garden is normally a planted or turfed area,  and a courtyard is often surrounded by walls.
But one restaurant might call its paved area a "terrace" just because they like the sound of the word.  The choice of word is for marketing not meaning.
As with most synonyms, there is a fair amount of overlap of sense.

A patio is in the back/side and/or somewhat enclosed. A terrace is not and only has to be adjoining.

@Lambie  That's too prescriptive.  There's nothing in the word "patio" that means it has to be enclosed, or on the back/side.  It does mean "paved", but that would be interpreted quite generously.  Mostly the choice of word is for marketing, not meaning.

I doubt you get many roadside patios in the UK. There is an architectural difference. UK, Collins, Meaning 1: 1. an open inner courtyard, esp one in a Spanish or Spanish-American house. You get terrace in the UK, but I doubt there is much patio dining re restaurants.

But we must take care not to be overly prescriptive.  Because this confuses the OP.  This OP wants very strong and clear separation of word meanings, and English (or other natural languages) don't work that way, and language teachers should take care not to create distinctions where they don't exist

James, in my opinion, a restaurant patio is enclosed or fenced in even if with bushes. Whereas a terrace is open for the world to see. That is a basic difference.

https://www.archdictionary.com/patio#google_vignette patio
Similar to a terrace, a patio is an outdoor extension of a building, situated above the ground level, and open to the sky. Colloquially, a patio is a more informal space than a terrace.

Sure,  this is what my point is.... patio/terrace  have similar meanings and the choice of word is therefore not determined by meaning but by something else such as the linguistic taste of the copywriter.

No, because it can very well mean an enclosed space.

canadian-english
Restaurants have patios. Although, in Montreal, we've borrowed the French word, terrasse /tə'ræs/.
"Terrace" /'terəs/ is used for a place outside a house specifically. It can also be called a "patio".
These aren't hard-and-fast definitions, but this is generally how they're used. On the other hand, the City of Montreal uses "terrace" as the equivalent of terrasse in French and you'll also see a rooftop or otherwise elevated patio referred to as a terrace, for example in this tourist guide from mtl.org.

houses and restaurants can have patios or terraces. Terrace comes Old French. Both can be a place to eat. See patio service by town: Canada. https://visitwindsoressex.ca/restaurants1/patios/ See terrace dining: Canada Terrace Dining Returns to Mission Hill Family Estate on May 11th https://scoutmagazine.ca/terrace-dining-returns-to-mission-hill-family-estate-on-may-11th/ And there is NO difference between the countries in terms of the meanings of the words terrace and patio.

@Lambie In your second link, "Terrace" is a proper noun. Read the body: "... outdoor Terrace restaurant ..."

It makes no difference. If a restaurant has a terrace and it serves food there, it's terrace dining. Here's another in Toronto: There’s nothing like dining on a terrace in the summertime. Vancouver’s popular Black+Blue Steakhouse from Glowbal Restaurant Group just opened in Toronto. https://livingluxe.ca/a-place-in-the-sun/

@Lambie That's odd... If you click through to the Black+Blue link, they exclusively use the word "patio". I guess "terrace" is used, but rarely.

Do you own or operate a bar, restaurant, café, grocery store or ice cream shop and want to build a commercial terrace (aka a sidewalk cafe) on the sidewalk, road or any other part of public property adjacent to your property? Learn about the applicable standards that you must meet. https://montreal.ca/en/how-to/build-commercial-terrace-public-property A terrace is NOT a patio. They are different structures. Patios are generally enclosed on the sides, terraces are not.

@Lambie I just saw a similar page myself. I edited my answer to clarify the situation.

@Lambie "Patios are generally enclosed on the sides, terraces are not." - Source?

Personal knowledge and experience. Look at the Montreal rules for them. That does not mean this extends to all of Canada. It's not a good idea to mix French and English either. And Montreal is famous for that.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
